# Ubercart payment

Tags: 7, ubercart, payment-gateways

How can I configure payment for ubercart?

I want default checkout to be worked or credit card option to get money to my paypal account. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following abstract from the [link](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/3356/configuring_paypal_website_payments_standard_wps) for ubercart payment using paypal:

PP Account Settings:

Signup for a PayPal account.
Before you can use WPS you need to sign up for a PP account. We recommend using this link to tell PayPal you registered through Ubercart. They in turn support the continued development of our project.

Open a business account (optional).
Although this step is optional, it is recommended for you to keep your personal and business PayPal accounts separate. Opening a business account is preferable because it allows you to use a business name on the PayPal checkout pages and in theory allows you to keep your private name separate. Presenting a business name to customers will help build customer confidence.

Go through the approval process to verify your account. This will require a bank account and correct contact information, possibly more. You can always contact their customer service if you get stumped here.
Configure PayPal account settings.
Login to your PayPal account and go to the profile page/tab. There are many options here but only a few are required to get WPS working with UC.

Setting up WPS:

Click on "Website Payment Preferences" under the "Selling Preferences" section.
Enable "Auto Return".

Set the "Return URL" to http://www.yourdomain.com/cart/checkout/complete

Enable "Paypal Account Optional" (optional). This will make it so customers are not forced to create a PayPal account during checkout.

Save your settings.

Setting up IPN:

Click on "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" under the "Selling Preferences" section.

Make sure that "Instant Payment Notification (IPN)" is not
checked.
Make sure that no IPN URL is set. UC provides this automatically.
* Note: When you login to PayPal, you may get taken to a "Getting Started Steps" page. Steps 1 and 2 are required and involve opening your business account and getting verified. However, step 3 is not required. You do not have to create any buttons or links as UC handles redirecting users to PayPal automatically.

Ubercart PayPal Settings

Enable uc_payment and uc_paypal modules at "admin/build/modules".

Configure PayPal WPS settings at admin/store/settings/payment/edit/methods:

Click the "Enable" checkbox for WPS.

Expand the "PayPal Website Payments Standard settings" fieldset and make the following changes:

Enter your PayPal account e-mail address in the appropriate field.

Set the "PayPal server" to "Live" (versus Sandbox) when you're ready to process orders.

The other fields are self-explanatory and based upon your requirements. Be sure to set them per your needs.

Configure your Checkout Settings at admin/store/settings/checkout. You probably want to make sure you've enabled the following two options:

New customers receive an e-mail with their account details.

Anonymous checkout.

Enable Automatic order update in WorkFlow-NG module by going to "admin/build/workflow-ng"

Click "Edit" for the Update order status on full payment
Tick "Active" checkbox.

Click "Submit"

For using Report module first you have to enable the Statistics
module by going to "admin/build/modules"

Now enable Report feature by going to "admin/store/settings/reports"
Choose "Payment Received" under "Report Statuses"